# How to programmatically forward one controller to another in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to programmatically forward from one method in a controller to another method using spring mvc 3.0

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public void getData(@RequestBody LazyTreeGridInput lazyTreeGridInput,
            HttpServletResponse response){


 if(someCondition){

    //forward to getParents


}else{
     //forward to children
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "forward". Have one method call another? Or have the servlet return an HTTP forward?

Answer (score 2):

You can see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example/) various ways to redirect using spring mvc 3.0.

***UPDATE:***

If you are more interested in forwarding, you should make your controllers available in this controller, and just call the method you wish to forward to.

Comment: I dont want to redirect it I want to forward it

Answer (score 1):

```
if (someCondition) {
    return "redirect:/parentsUrl";
} else {
    return "redirect:childUrl";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the other controller's url in the modelAndView which your handler method returns? Does calling the controller method directly the same as forwarding it?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a String instead, and the String being the forward url.
    @RequestMapping({"/getData"})
    public String execute(Model model) {

```
if (someCondition) {
    return "forward:/parentsUrl";
} else {
    return "forward:/childUrl";
}
}
```